# Wordpress on iOS requires refresh before uploaded pictures can be seen or viewed

Tags: wordpress, mobile, image-uploading

I am launching a wordpress based website which has a custom wordpress open_media window. When I am adding media from iPhone (in Chrome or Safari), I am able to upload pictures from my photo library but they do not show up immediately for use. I get no errors. To find the photo I have to exit out of the media window and refresh my browser then reenter the open media window and the picture will be there.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

```js
function open_media_window() {
    var upload = "";
    $post_div = $(this).closest('.bizimg-select');
    if (this.window === undefined) {

      if($(this).hasClass('bizimg-select')){
        upload = "bizimg";

      }
      if($(this).hasClass('vcard-file')){
        upload = "vcard";

      }
      if(upload=='bizimg'||upload==""){
        this.window = wp.media({
                title: 'Upload my Bizcard Bizimg',
                library: {type: 'image/*'},
                multiple: false,
                button: {text: 'Insert'}
            });
      }
      if((upload=='vcard')){
        this.window = wp.media({
                title: 'Upload my Bizcard vCard',
                library: {type: 'text/x-vcard'},
                multiple: false,
                button: {text: 'Insert'}
            });
      }

      var self = this;
      this.window.on('select', function() {
              var files = self.window.state().get('selection').toArray();
              var first = files[0].toJSON();

              if(upload=='bizimg'){
               //do some stuff here

              }
             
              if(upload=='vcard'){
                //do a bunch of stuff here
                }

          });

        }
    this.window.open();
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken that this issue was restricted to mobile connections only. After much digging and trying to learn more about js backbone and wordpress wp.media (which remains relatively undocumented, by the way), I did figure it out. Using 'image' instead of 'image/*' in the library options allowed the upload to load into the media library screen. 'image/*' was the problem. See below the options that worked for me.

```
   wp.media({
                title: 'Upload my Bizcard Bizimg',
                library: {type: 'image'},
                multiple: false,
                button: {text: 'Insert'}
            });
```